# Flutter: How to wrap an ImagePicker/VideoPicker with other Widgets?

Tags: image, flutter, video

I would like to customize the video recording screen by wrapping it with some other widgets. Use-Case: I want to ask the users a question they have to answer via a video. I would like to show the question as an overlay to the camera.

Don't find a way to customize the ImagePicker package.

CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION:

```
videoFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(
          preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front,
          source: imageSource,
          maxDuration: Duration(seconds: 15));
```

Comment: no, you can't, because picker activty is not same with your app, you can show question to user, then user must click on key to open picker

Comment: any other options to access device-camera and customize UI?